# GtkStatusBar gets stuck at a /random/ position and wants me to mousehover button

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk, gtk3

I will keep it simple

I have the function `inside_thread` that runs a `while` loop and calls the function `update_progressbar` that simply updates a `GtkStatusBar`.

I am calling `inside_thread` in a thread using `g_thread_new("processing", GThreadFunc, NULL);` from a callback function `on_starter_clicked`.

---

It tends to do the job, it works fast and it updates the status bar according to the progress of the `while` loop.

The problem is that sometimes (at unspecified place) the progress bar gets stuck and it gets unstuck if I mouseenter or mouseleave a button in the application. Very strange behavior I must admit

What could be wrong?

Comment: Some graphics packages require that all UI updates happen on the main thread.

Comment: How is that explaining the behavior? It updates to a point and then freezes and waits me to mousehover or over a button to make it continue.

Comment: You're racing the UI thread; if you lose the race, anything can happen. It just so happens that not updating the view is one of those things, probably because you updated the value while it was drawing once so it didn't think it needed to draw again. I don't know for sure. You can instead try updating the progress bar using `gdk_threads_idle_add()`, which will schedule a callback to run on the UI thread.

Comment: I tried with `gdk_threads_idle_add()` twice before and nothing happened. It didn't work. Might be because of the lack of examples.. I got something wrong.

Comment: If gtk requires updates on the main thread, and you do updates on other threads, then anything can happen. The question is whether gtk functions are thread-safe. The documentation may answer that question for every function, or (like the packages that I've used) there's just one statement in the introduction that says that all UI updates need to happen on the main thread.

Comment: I don't know how to update the progress bar in the main thread. I am using a very specific fraction and I can not simply call it through a timer. It doesn't work with signals.. and if I put it in a loop.. it will refresh once the loop ends.

Comment: Oh right, `gdk_threads_add_idle()` is asynchronous, so your progress bar will be updated at some point in the future. If you want to use a progress bar, you'll either have to a) add some sort of synchronization mechanism, or b) change your thread to be a `gdk_threads_add_idle()` callback (you may find its repeating facility useful here). And yes, GTK+ is *not* multithreading-safe; everything must be done on the thread that calls `gtk_init()`.

Comment: @andlabs yes it didn't work. It updated the statusbar once after the whole loop finished....

Comment: These functions with the likes of `gdk_threads_add_idle()` simply schedule a function call, according to its priority and by the usage of `gdk_threads_add_idle()` the priority defaults to 200 (`G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE`) but that doesn't even matter.

Comment: progressbar* Sorry I often get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't update the GtkProgressBar from another thread. There are two solutions to your problem, and both involve `gdk_threads_idle_add()`:

**1. Wait for the Idle Callback**

In this case,your thread would schedule the progress bar update with `gdk_threads_add_idle()`, then wait for it to finish. I don't know what the best way to do this with GLib is, but there's probably something you can do (GMutex?). The idea is this:

```
gboolean updateProgressBar(gpointer data)
{
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(progressbar, value);
    tellOtherThreadToContinue();
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;        // == FALSE
}

gpointer otherThread(gpointer data)
{
    while (condition) {
        doStep();
        gdk_threads_idle_add(updateProgressBar, NULL);
        waitForProgressBarToBeUpdated();
    }
    return (gpointer) 0;
}
```

**2. Forego the Thread Entirely and Loop the Idle Callback**

If the idle callback returns `G_SOURCE_CONTINUE` (== `TRUE`), GTK+ will schedule your function again for the next idle period. You can take advantage of this to rewrite your `while` loop as an idle callback:

```
gboolean loop(gpointer data)
{
    if (condition)
        return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
    doStep();
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(progressbar, value);
    return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}

// in your code, start the loop going with
gdk_threads_idle_add(loop, NULL);
```

Regardless of what you choose, you can take advantage of the `data` parameter to both the idle callback and the thread to pass data those functions would need around. Just be careful not to pass a pointer to a local variable to the idle callback, as that might run after your function returns (and the variable goes out of scope/ceases to exist).

Note that regardless of what you do, you'll be waiting for the progress bar to update (and in the latter case, redraw). If things become too slow, you may want to look into updating the progress bar in chunks. This, however, depends entirely on how many steps you have.

Comment: I can't update the progress bar or I shouldn't update the progress bar from another thread? Because this is what I'm doing.. and what works.

Comment: Also these two ways (assuming they actually work) I can see will be slower than my current approach. (2)The processing could be HUGE this is why.. people add progress bar and this is why it has to be in another thread - for performance. (1) besides, scheduling the process instead of scheduling the progress bar is not for any preference ..at all because the process remains the the most important part from the program, not some graphical indication.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is very specific. Assuming you want to update your progress bar according to the progress of a loop you have to do 3 things.

- Create a thread in which you will run your loop

  - Ensure the loop with debugging and if there is a need for mutexes
- **[a]** Schedule the progress bar update when GTK is able to using [gdk_threads_add_idle ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk-threads-add-idle)
  and do note that this function will call the progress bar updating function with `G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE` and let it be. Otherwise if your curious look at [g_idle_add_full ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add-full)
- **[b]** Terminate the thread when it is no longer needed (progress 100%)

GTK+ is not multithreading safe. It can not always re-draw components, especially if it is busy, deadlocked in an unspecified iteration of the main-loop. It is a matter of synchronization, which is why you need to schedule the update.

---

**[a]** Since you have values to give to the progress bar updating functions in order to do your interval arithmetics, you have to pass them as an array to give to the function.

**[b]** The other problem occurs at the end of the whole process. Your application will crash unless you ensure to no longer update the progress bar. You can imply a mutex or any sort of restrictions you come up with.
**IMPORTANT:** This could not be the only reason for crash after the processing. As the other answer clearly states.. you can not just update gtk component through another thread. To omit this, simply call `gtk_main_iteration()` after the loop, before the thread terminates so it iterates one more time to update the progress bar properly and on time.

---

A simple exemplification with pseudo-code implementation of the whole thing:

```
gboolean on_starter_clicked () // callback function
{
    g_thread_new("processing", proceed_thread, NULL);
}

gpointer proceed_thread (gpointer data) // processing-thread
{
    while(1)
    {
        // Process whatever needs to be processed
        // break when it needs to be breaked

        gint data[] = { partial, full };
        gdk_threads_add_idle(update_progressbar, data);
    }
    gtk_main_teration();
}

gboolean update_progressbar (gpointer data) // updating function
{
    gint *d = (gint*)data;
    gdouble fraction = ( (d[0] * 100.0) / d[1] ); // Calculating your interval

    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(...), fraction / 100.0 );
}
```

---

One more thing. You may notice that there will be a slightly decrease of the movement smoothness of the progress indicator. That because GTK+ schedules the update, which is fully understandable that doesn't mean "immediately".

Comment: Um, are you sure you wanted to answer your own question like this, in the third person and built from our comments? And this answer doesn't solve the problem you said you had about the GtkProgressBar only redrawing at the end of your thread.

Comment: This solved my problem? Who else can confirm that but me. I also know why does it fix it. Comments helped. And yes.. of course progress bar will update after the loop, in case the loop is in the main thread.

Comment: In the 3rdperson as for speaking to the community /if/ someone gets into that problem.